# Matching Query Error while trying to make Case Insensitive Usernames in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to Override the user model to make usernames case insensitive and allow semicolons. I haven't added the code for semicolons yet. I am getting a matching query error while trying to create a superuser.

When I run `python manage.py createsuperuser` I get a matching query error

Here is my code

models.py

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import (

    AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager

)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
    
        return self.get(**{self.model.USERNAME_FIELD + '__iexact': username})
    
    def create_user(self, username, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
    
        if not username:
    
            raise ValueError("Users must have an username address")
    
        if not password:
       
            raise ValueError("Users must have a password")
    
        user_obj = self.model(
    
            username = self.get_by_natural_key(username)
    
        )
    
        user_obj.set_password(password) # change user password
    
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
    
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
    
        user_obj.active = is_active
    
        user_obj.save(using=self._db)
    
        return user_obj
    
    

    def create_staffuser(self, username, password=None):
    
        user = self.create_user(
    
            username,
    
            password=password,
    
            is_staff=True
    
        )
    
    return user
    
    
    def create_superuser(self, username, password=None):
    
        user = self.create_user(
    
        username,
     
        password=password,
    
        is_staff=True,
    
        is_admin=True
    
        )
    
    return user
    

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    
    #full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True) # can login
    
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False) # staff user non superuser
    
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # superuser
    
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    # confirm = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    # confirmed_date = models.DateTimeField(default=False)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username' #username
    
    # USERNAME_FIELD and password are required by default
    
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [] #['full_name'] #python manage.py createsuperuser
    
    objects = UserManager()
    
    def __str__(self):
    
        return self.username
    
    def get_full_name(self):
    
        return self.username
    
    def get_short_name(self):
    
        return self.username
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    
        return True
    
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
    
        return True
    
    
    
    def is_staff(self):
    
        return self.staff
    
    
    
    def is_admin(self):
    
        return self.admin
    
    
    
    def is_active(self):
    
        return self.active
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

User = get_user_model()

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):

    list_display = ('username', 'admin')
    
    list_filter = ('admin', 'staff', 'active')
    
    fieldsets = (
    
    (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
    
    ('Personal info', {'fields': ()}),
    
    ('Permissions', {'fields': ('admin', 'staff', 'active',)}),
    
    )
    
    # add_fieldsets is not a standard ModelAdmin attribute. UserAdmin
    
    # overrides get_fieldsets to use this attribute when creating a user.
    
    add_fieldsets = (
    
    (None, {
    
    'classes': ('wide',),
    
    'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2')}
    
    ),
    
    )
    
    search_fields = ('username',)
    
    ordering = ('username',)
    
    filter_horizontal = ()
    

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Here is the error that I'm getting

`account.models.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.`

Comment: you sure you've migrated the database?

Comment: yes. I think the problem is with the get_by_natural_key() function. I think there needs to be some try except clause there but I'm not sure.

Comment: can you try to remove the ```def create_superuser```? not sure what you are overriding with that.

Comment: I removed the code and the call to it. And it seems to be working

The code seems to be working when I change it to this. 

```user_obj = self.model (username = username)```

I'm wondering how I make the users case insensitive

Comment: can you post your views.py?

Comment: My views.py is empty. I'm creating the users through the shell.